# Firefox/Chrome, jQuery, Ajax: can't submit specific character lengths in POST data field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

When I submit data using jQuery's ajax function via POST, it times out at specific intervals of character lengths on one page of my site. I can submit less than 16k characters, then I can submit 24k characters, then about 30k then 35k ... and various character lengths in between don't work. It's consistent yet totally random. This only happens on 1 page on the site. I created a blank page that does nothing but submit the number of characters I choose (see below) and it always works. So it's just the one page that has this problem, and only in FF & Crome (Safari is good, IE works half the time), and not just on my computer. Submitting the data normally, as a form, works totally fine. I'm just really really confused. Is it client side or server side?

example:

```
var string = '';

for (var z = 0; z < 20000; z++) {
    string += 'b';
}

$.ajax({

    url: 'test.php',
    data: 'd=' + string,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: 15000,
    beforeSend: function () {
        alert('sending');
    },
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert('timeout');
    }

});
```

So I've figured out that my testing method was bad, since I was going the above test over http while the rest of the site runs as HTTPS. As soon as I switch to HTTPS the above script fails at the same character count intervals in FF. Even regular forms don't work anymore above 15k characters. And there appears to be something wrong with SSL certificate.

Comment: what are you doing exactly with the string on that one page?

Comment: this might help http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12531/ssl-with-get-and-post